# Match a whole word in a String in AS3

Tags: regex, string, actionscript-3, flash, search

I need some help matching a whole word from a string. Can anyone recommend a way to do this?

Example:

```
var keywords:String = "att, attractive, attaboy, attack, attach";
```

I want to be able to search for just "att" and not get any other results.

Comment: A bit confused for exactly what you at looking for here. You want a true/false if "att" exists in the string? if it is a full word? Or do you want the entire word IF it contains "att"

Answer (score 4):

Here's a regex for just the word "att":

`\batt\b`

`\b` matches a word boundary.

Comment: Do you have any advice on how to use this within AS3?

Comment: read the documentation!  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/RegExp.html

Comment: @Zero no, I've never used AS3. But I use regex a LOT, because they're awesome.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a true / false whether the word was found in a string:

```
    public static function contains(p_string:String, p_char:String):Boolean
    {
        if (p_string == null)
            return false;

        return p_string.indexOf(p_char) != -1;
    }
```

Used as:

```
contains(keywords, "att"); // would return true
```

Comment: Not exactly what I am looking for. That would still work if "att" was not in that list if keywords. With this code, it will pull "att" from words that contain "att". I want to look for "att" specifically. Make sense?

Comment: Your question was not clear what you were seeking.  Yes, this function tests whether a string is contained within a string.

Answer (score 0):

This could work but you need to get rid of the spaces after the commas:

```
var keywords:String = "att,attractive,attaboy,attack,attach";

var arr:Array = keywords.split(",");
if (arr.indexOf("att") == -1) {
    trace("false");
} else {
    trace("true");
}
```

Comment: Assuming we can't change the input format, you could split on `", "`, if it's guaranteed.